# Mysql Insert Where Column is Like Wildcard Query

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to inset values into every row where one of the column values contains a specific string.

```
INSERT INTO `cases_index`(`related`) VALUES (`Alabama`) WHERE `court` LIKE '%Alabama%'
```

So int eh above example I have a row with three columns:

court | federal | related

I want to insert the word 'Alabama' into the 'related' column for any row where the court column contains the word 'Alabama' (i.e. 'District Court of Alabama').

The above line spits out the following syntax error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE `cases_index`(`court`) LIKE '%Alabama%'' at line 1

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the syntax error in your query, if you want to update existing rows you should use an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE cases_index
SET related='Alabama'
WHERE court LIKE '%Alabama%'
```

Just for completeness, `INSERT` queries add new rows to the table, so a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

While the UPDATE answers are what you are looking for, INSERT does allow WHERE clause.

Refer to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
    SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
    FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

But the answer to this is what trgdor wrote:

```
UPDATE cases_index
SET related='Alabama'
WHERE court LIKE '%Alabama%'
```

Comment: I personally don't consider this is allowing the clause in the `INSERT`. The `WHERE` clause is allowed in the `SELECT`, and the `INSERT` query allows an inner `SELECT`, but the `WHERE` clause (or any other clause of the `SELECT`) is not related to the `INSERT` query. Nice point anyway.

Comment: @trogdor The other answer which is now deleted read something like "WHERE is not allowed with INSERT". That I felt was misleading. I did copy your answer (and referenced :) ) because that's what Thomas wanted to do and I upvoted your answer!